# NetBeans 8.0 unable to locate Android SDK

Tags: java, android, netbeans, sdk, ubuntu-13.10

I've installed the Android SDK into NetBeans 8.0 in Ubuntu 13.10 and I've specified the SDK location in Tools>Option>Miscellaneous>Android and key loaded too.
But when i create new Android project it says to me that the SDK location is not specified

How can i resolve this problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

Go to nbandroid.org and install the Android plugin and also ask your questions there, on the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

go into the android sdk folder, run tools/android update sdk --no-ui

Answer (score 0):

You may miss the android platform tool. see this: https://bitbucket.org/nbandroid/nbandroid/issues/28/android-sdk-location-clears-upon-pushing

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. It is better to include a summary of the link in your post, in case the link goes stale at a later date.